# How to use PeekMessage to retrieve every messages except input (mouse + keyboard)

Tags: c++, winapi, events, input

I have somewhere in my code a loop function that call `PeekMessage` in order to retrieve events.

Currently it looks like this:

```
while (PeekMessage(&Message, NULL, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
{
    // Process events
}
```

Now I would like to manage input in a different location, meaning I'd like to retrieve messages such as `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_MOUSEMOVE` (mouse and keyboard events) in a different place, at a different time of my main loop.

`PeekMessage`'s third and fourth arguments allow to define a range of message to return, so I could use this, using provided macros `WM_KEYFIRST`, `WM_KEYLAST`, `WM_MOUSEFIRST` and `WM_MOUSELAST`. But it's unconvenient because I have two ranges to check for input, and therefore three ranges for everything remaining.

The last parameter is a flag and I could pass `PM_REMOVE | PM_QS_INPUT` for input. But then, what should I pass in the other loop, where I want to get every other messages? There is no `PM_QS_EVERYTHING_EXCEPT_INPUT` macro...

What would be the most elegant way to do this?

Comment: Your last, non-existent flag could be visualized as `~PM_QS_INPUT`, which could be combined with `PM_REMOVE` via bitwise OR.

Comment: Yes, that could be a solution. But it doesn't satisfy me because this flag has two different sementics: 1) what type of message to retrieve (PM_QS_*), and 2) what to do with the message (PM_REMOVE, PM_NOREMOVE, but also PM_NOYIELD which I don't want to set, and potentially any new flag on the next version of Windows). I didn't find any macro to separate those two sementics, although looking at the actual values, the 16 first bits are reserved for the second one.

Comment: My mistake, you should be using the `~PM_QS_INPUT`, but only masking the range of bits that applies to flags of that type. Had a brain fail there. So if the last half are for that, the first half would be 0, and all but `PM_QS_INPUT` in the last half would be 1.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem you are facing. Can't you call PeekMessage twice, once with WM_KEYFIRST and a second time with WM_MOUSEFIRST ? The test you will do (something like `while(PeekMessage(...WM_KEYFIRST...) || PeekMessage(...WM_MOUSEFIRST...))`  is the same an enhanced, multi-range PeekMessage would do.

Comment: Yes I can, but I would also need to call three PeekMessage three times in the other loop, with ranges BEFORE_KEY_RANGE, BETWEEN_KEY_AND_MOUSE_RANGE, and AFTER_MOUSE_RANGE, so that would make five calls. And I still have to assume that the Key range is before the Mouse range, which is bad (or, ok, I could test which one is the first, and adapt... but that make a lot of dirty code, which is why I'm asking if an elegant way to do this exists). There is no way (afaik) to iterate through the message queue, so I have to rely on the options PeekMessage gives me for filtering.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use "Filters". Win32 calls that "hooks", take a look to msdn's SetWindowsHookEx function. you've got the possibility to install a thread specific filter for keyboard and mouse messages. Then you can push messages to a queue of your maintenance and access it manually later on (knowing you can remove the related messages from the public Queue for that thread if you chose to, from the hook, so that only your user-queue will have the messages).
though, you could simply also directly push to this use-queue directly from the PeekMessage switch in every case that is of interest for you.